# A 3D problem on the range of angles

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

[image]

$CD$, of length $14$ units, is a line fixed on the ground. $AB$ is a thin rod fixed in the air. A ring, which is attached to $AB$, can slide freely on $AB$. An elastic band (remaining taut all the time) passing through the ring is fixed to the ends $C$ and $D$ such that the triangle(s) so formed are always isosceles with the vertical angle $= \theta$, [$\theta$ remains as acute in the whole process.]. At some point $Q$ on $AB$, $∠AQD = 90^0$. Find the change of $\theta$ as the ring moves from $A$ to $Q$ and from $Q$ to $B$.

I found $\cos \theta = ... = 1 - \dfrac {98}{h^2} $

Comment: I am not clear what is the vertical angle $\,\theta.\,$ Where would it be on the picture?

Comment: Which triangles exactly are isosceles ?

Comment: @Vlad When the ring is at A, ADC is isosceles with AD = AC and the vertical angle is $\theta = \angle DAC$. When it is at Q, QD = QC and $\theta = \angle DQC$. The same is for the ring at B

Comment: @Lucian Pls see the above comment. Note that the triangles are isosceles but h, the length of the equal legs changes from time to time. That is AD is not the same as QD.

Comment: For the description to happen, I guess the rod AB has to be placed in the position whose projection on the plane ADC is the perpendicular bisector of DC of triangle ADC.

Comment: @Vlad Extra condition has been added inside the square bracket.

Comment: @Lucian Extra condition has been added inside the square bracket.